# No adapter attached; skipping layout when using cursor loader

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to populate RecyclerView in `onLoadFinished()` with the cursor data returned from a `CursorLoader`. The RecyclerView is populated as it is expected,
but I am still getting the same error "No adapter attached; skipping layout"

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);

    //attach Layout Manager to RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(newLinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));  

    //attach adapter to RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a couple of days i managed to figure out the issue...what i did was to create an instance of my RecyclerView Adapter inside my onActivityCreated passing in only the context of my Fragment to the Adapter's constructor and set the Adapter to my RecyclerView

```
recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

So, the RecyclerView Framework has an adapter attached and thus no layout was skipping. The cursor data ara being passed(swapped) to the RecyclerView Adapter from the onLoadFinished() and onLoadReset() methods of the CursorLoader respectively

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    recyclerViewAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    recyclerViewAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

the swapCursor method has been customed implemented inside my RecyclerView Adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of when you attach an adapter, your `RecyclerView` is going need to lay itself out on the screen as soon as the containing Activity/Fragment needs to layout- that is, when the screen is first displayed to the user.

That means that before your `CursorLoader` has finished loading, your layout will likely be displayed to the user. For this to happen, the `RecyclerView` will need to query its adapter to figure out what to display.

You should instead set your layout manager and an empty adapter when your Activity/Fragment is first created, then update the contents of the adapter once your cursor finishes loading.

Comment: by setting an empty adapter you mean creating an instance of my adapter class using the default constructor?

Comment: I would use the same instance of your adapter throughout the life of your `RecyclerView`, but just ensure that it support being created with no items initially.

Comment: i do think indeed that the error does not affect the overall performance of the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

This error message shown when the view is created. There is a recyclerview but not adapter was set. I will suggest to create and set the adapter to recyclerview onCreate or in onCreateView (if fragment). Then just set the cursor or data to the adapter onLoadFinished and notify your adapter for data change..

or just ignore the error message.. No harm done by the error message ;-)

Comment: this is what i gonna do..just ingoring the error message...anyway thank's for your help..

Comment: But if your recyclerview is in fragment and you are using loader then best to creat the adapter at oncreateview with null check before create so that each time resume to fragment you can avoid recreating of the adapter.. This will also hold the state of the adapter.